# How could I fetch a secret from Secrets Manager and Pass it to my SSM Run Command Document via lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I have a secret (the AWS Access Key, Secret Key, Region) stored in secrets manager. Now I have to retrieve it from my lambda and pass that as parameters to my SSM Run command document which will be triggered by my lambda. When trying, I am not able to fetch the value from Secret using my lambda. Here's my below code.

````
import base64
client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  response = client.get_secret_value(
    SecretId = 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:*************:secret:aws/credentials/******'
   )
  return response```

When I execute this I got this error (earlier even without error it gives null response or identation issues) 

```Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 28, 13, 28, 47, 798000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError"
}``` 


**What am I missing here?**
````

Answer (score 2):

The errorMessage seems unrelated to the actual question.  If you want to use the RunCommand API from your lambda function, all you need to do is associate an [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html) with the lambda function that has the appropriate SSM permissions.  Secrets Manager is used to store longer-term credentials and is not intended to store AWS API keys.  Use IAM roles for this whenever possible as they are ephemeral/short-lived.